# javascript validation empty field with error messages

Tags: javascript

Can any one please tell me the wrong of this code, I just want to j=give an error message when the first_name  is empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').click(function(){ 
      var first_name=$('#first_name').val();

 if(first_name==="" ){
                 $('#first_name').css('background-color','#D8D8D8');
                 $('#fNameErr').show();
                return false;
            }
            else{
                 $('#first_name').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
                 $('#fNameErr').hide();
                return true;
               }

 }); 

 });  
    </script>
```

HTML

```
 <form name="myForm" action="../controller/users.php" method="POST" 
         enctype="multipart/form-data" >

            <table align="left" width="700" height="330">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value=""size="45" id="first_name"/>
                            <div id="fNameErr" class="err"><b>Please Enter First Name</b></div></td>    
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Plus, your code is missing a closing `</form>` tag as well as a possible missing submit button with `submit` as an `id`. If that is your full/actual code, add it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i need to know whether you downloaded jquery file from ,if not do it first.. else jquery wont work.. follow this link http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js, save this file in the folder where is your code is...name of the file i used is 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js'

then there was some more mistakes in your code. you need to give a submit button first with the id 'submit', which you used in your script's 3rd line, then need to close form tag..
correct code is..

```
<html><script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').click(function(){ 
      var first_name=$('#first_name').val();
 if(first_name=="" ){
                 $('#first_name').css('background-color','#D8D8D8');
                 $('#fNameErr').show();
                return false;
            }
            else{
                 $('#first_name').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
                 $('#fNameErr').hide();
                return true;
               }

 }); 

 });  
    </script>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" action="../controller/users.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <table align="left" width="700" height="330">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value=""size="45" id="first_name"/>
                            <div id="fNameErr" class="err"><b>Please Enter First Name</b></div></td>    
                    </tr>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
                    </form>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

try to learn basics first.. Accept my answer if it helps..  :)